# Using these 2 build options in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I debug a project and there is an error in my code (e.g. a method returns something and when I consume that method, I don't put the returned data into a variable) the popup asking me to run the last successful build comes up.

How exactly do I configure this? Also, in what scenario does the Visual Studio build order come in handy? I once built a solution, and it couldn't build one project because a dependent project was not built beforehand. I guess this one possible scenario? Any others?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your solution consists of multiple projects (the only time this is necessary) you need to set up the project dependencies so when you debug the main application all the sub projects are built in the correct order.

Right click over the project and select "Project Dependencies".